# Replace black areas with white color

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, colors

I'm looking for a fast algorithm which will replace black areas with a white color. I have a set of images (some examples below).

- [Image 1](http://s18.postimage.org/4ljutzx2h/qwe_00001_00032.jpg)
- [Image 2](http://s18.postimage.org/dhz8bod2h/qwe_00001_00040.jpg)
- [Image 3](http://s7.postimage.org/zczdc0p3f/zxcvbn_00002_00002.png)
- [Image 4](http://s8.postimage.org/4iob4hnut/qwe_00001_00001.jpg)

As you can see the images can contain elements of black color (e.g. text, borders - maps) - so I can't just simply replace the colors... You can notice that the black areas always start from the border of an image. How to get rid of them?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is your current algorithm and what bottleneck(s) have you discovered?

Comment: I'm starting scanning line by line on 4 sides (left - horizontally, right - horizontally, top - vertically, bot - vertically) and going until I find a pixel with different colour than black. But there are 2 problems here: 1. What if there is a black point on the border of a black area and a map? 2. Very naive and slow algorithm. I thought that I could use that black areas are always on the borders and they are always rectangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flood fill the black area, starting from the borders. Paint areas larger than a threshold white.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know `flood fill` concept:)